# Identifying and replacing stacking TRS jack

Tags: audio, identification, speakers

The center/Sub jack on my inspire p7800 connection is terrible. I kinda have to pull it out slightly to work and reached a point there it doesnt work at all. I can't seem to find a replacement part. I've never seen this stackable connector before. Both are TRS.

I need to replace the orange one.

edit: both are TRS

edit: the back says: <del>TC  F</del>

edit: back of grn/blk: TC F
back of org/gry: TC A

[image: input jacks for Inspire p7800]

Comment: Have you tried asking the manufacturer of the device this is on?

Comment: @Hearth yea I guess I might as well try. Creative has been pretty awful with their support in the past but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

I would not be surprised if the connector is no longer produced and/or was specifically custom-made for Creative -- so there are no replacements.

Some alternative ideas:

**Check the soldering first**. Maybe the connector is fine, and it is just bad solder joints?

If the solder joints are fine, your best bet is to get a panel-mount connector, and mount it directly to rear panel in the unused space above other connectors. (You'll need to use some wires so you have enough space to put the panel back). It is going to be ugly, but who is going to look there? It will also be a pain to assemble, but you only need to do it once. Example: [CUI SJ1-3534](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/cui-devices/SJ1-3534/738694)

[image: CUI SJ1-3534 connector]

If you really want to keep the stock look, there are dual (non-stacking) audio connectors. If you are lucky, they will have the same pinout, and you will be able to remove both old ones and insert new connector. If you are unlucky, the pinout will be different and you have to update the traces / make the new holes. If you go this way, make sure to determine how the old connectors work (when the back is open, you can just see it directly; else you need to measure it with ohmmeter). Example: [35RAPC7JS](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/switchcraft-inc/35RAPC7JS/1289592)[image: 35RAPC7JS]